# Numpy : Add a 1d array (row) to an empty 2d array in Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I don't know the number of rows and columns of a 2d array (`a`) I need in advance:

```
a = np.empty( (0,0), dtype=np.uint8 )
a.ndim
2
```

I managed to convert each line I read from a file to an 1d array of bytes called `line`

I want to add/append each line to `a`, so I tried :

`np.vstack( (a,line) )`

but I get :
`ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

And if I call `a=np.append(a,line)`, the number of dimensions becomes `1`

Can you help ?

Comment: Have you tried gathering all the 1d arrays into a list and calling ```np.array``` on it?

Comment: @Anis What do you mean by `gathering` and how do I do that ?

Comment: Where does line come from? It may be possible to simplify your solution.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `line` is an array of `uint8`, example : `[201, 81, 237, 230]`

Comment: And where do you get it from? Is it part of a bigger list? Or do you call it inside some function?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I get it from reading a file line/line :

At first `line = 'c951ede6'`

Comment: @SebMa Okay. If you want a concise solution, the other answer is better. I've given you an answer that goes along your line of thinking.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You are absolutely right, I tried both solutions and the one from Tom Wyllie is both faster and simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays cannot be appended to. The easiest way for you to do what you are trying to achieve would be to use a list and call `np.asarray()` on it.

```
a = []
# Build list from file
a = np.asarray(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with `np.vstack`. The only requirement is that the arrays being stacked must have the same number of columns. Take a look at this:

```
array = None # initialise array to None first

for ...: # now inside the loop
    line = ... # read line from somewhere and get something like [201, 81, 237, 230]

    if array is None:
        array = line
    else: 
        array = np.vstack((array, line))
```

In terms of performance, this is actually a little more wasteful than just creating an array at the end out of a list. This is the problem with numpy arrays - they're immutable in terms of dimensions.

Comment: @COLDSPEED You are absolutely right, I tried both solutions and the one from Tom Wyllie is both faster and simpler.

Comment: @SebMa Cheers. :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED Bye :-)